# EXPLAIN SELECT Shows Type as ALL (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, query-optimization

I'm troubleshooting the performance of a rather complex SQL query I have here. When I run the following command, the results are outlined below...

```
EXPLAIN SELECT
    Import_Values.id,
    Import_Values.part_id,
    Import_Values.qty,
    Import_Values.note,
    Parts.partterminologyname,
    GROUP_CONCAT(BaseVehicle.YearID, ' ', Make.MakeName, ' ', Model.modelname, ' ', SubModel.SubModelName SEPARATOR ', '),
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(EngineDesignation.EngineDesignationName) SEPARATOR ', '),
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(EngineVIN.EngineVINName) SEPARATOR ', '),
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(EngineBase.Liter) SEPARATOR ', '),
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(EngineBase.CC) SEPARATOR ', '),
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(EngineBase.CID) SEPARATOR ', '),
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(EngineBase.Cylinders) SEPARATOR ', '),
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(EngineBase.BlockType) SEPARATOR ', '),
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(EngineBase.EngBoreIn) SEPARATOR ', '),
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(EngineBase.EngBoreMetric) SEPARATOR ', '),
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(EngineBase.EngStrokeIn) SEPARATOR ', '),
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(EngineBase.EngStrokeMetric) SEPARATOR ', '),
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(FuelDeliveryType.FuelDeliveryTypeName) SEPARATOR ', '),
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(FuelDeliverySubType.FuelDeliverySubTypeName) SEPARATOR ', '),
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(FuelSystemControlType.FuelSystemControlTypeName) SEPARATOR ', '),
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(FuelSystemDesign.FuelSystemDesignName) SEPARATOR ', '),
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(Aspiration.AspirationName) SEPARATOR ', '),
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(CylinderHeadType.CylinderHeadTypeName) SEPARATOR ', '),
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(FuelType.FuelTypeName) SEPARATOR ', '),
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(IgnitionSystemType.IgnitionSystemTypeName) SEPARATOR ', '),
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(Mfr.MfrName) SEPARATOR ', ')
    FROM 
    Import_Values
    INNER JOIN BaseVehicle 
        ON Import_Values.base_vehicle_id=BaseVehicle.BaseVehicleID
    INNER JOIN Parts 
        ON Import_Values.part_type_id=Parts.PartTerminologyID
    INNER JOIN Make
        ON BaseVehicle.MakeID=Make.MakeID
    INNER JOIN Model
        ON BaseVehicle.ModelID=Model.ModelID
    INNER JOIN Vehicle
        ON Import_Values.base_vehicle_id=Vehicle.BaseVehicleID
    INNER JOIN SubModel
        ON Vehicle.SubModelID=SubModel.SubModelID
    INNER JOIN VehicleToEngineConfig
        ON Vehicle.VehicleID=VehicleToEngineConfig.VehicleID
    INNER JOIN EngineConfig
        ON VehicleToEngineConfig.EngineConfigID=EngineConfig.EngineConfigID
    INNER JOIN EngineDesignation
        ON EngineConfig.EngineDesignationID=EngineDesignation.EngineDesignationID
    INNER JOIN EngineVIN
        ON EngineConfig.EngineVINID=EngineVIN.EngineVINID
    INNER JOIN EngineBase
        ON EngineConfig.EngineBaseID=EngineBase.EngineBaseID
    INNER JOIN FuelDeliveryConfig
        ON EngineConfig.FuelDeliveryConfigID=FuelDeliveryConfig.FuelDeliveryConfigID
    INNER JOIN FuelDeliveryType
        ON FuelDeliveryConfig.FuelDeliveryTypeID=FuelDeliveryType.FuelDeliveryTypeID
    INNER JOIN FuelDeliverySubType
        ON FuelDeliveryConfig.FuelDeliverySubTypeID=FuelDeliverySubType.FuelDeliverySubTypeID
    INNER JOIN FuelSystemControlType
        ON FuelDeliveryConfig.FuelSystemControlTypeID=FuelSystemControlType.FuelSystemControlTypeID
    INNER JOIN FuelSystemDesign
        ON FuelDeliveryConfig.FuelSystemDesignID=FuelSystemDesign.FuelSystemDesignID
    INNER JOIN Aspiration
        ON EngineConfig.AspirationID=Aspiration.AspirationID
    INNER JOIN CylinderHeadType
        ON EngineConfig.CylinderHeadTypeID=CylinderHeadType.CylinderHeadTypeID
    INNER JOIN FuelType
        ON EngineConfig.FuelTypeID=FuelType.FuelTypeID
    INNER JOIN IgnitionSystemType
        ON EngineConfig.IgnitionSystemTypeID=IgnitionSystemType.IgnitionSystemTypeID
    INNER JOIN Mfr
        ON EngineConfig.EngineMfrID=Mfr.MfrID
    GROUP BY part_id
```

The results indicate that the table Import_Values has 147377 rows and the type is 'ALL' and FuelDeliveryType has 3 rows and the type is 'ALL'. From what I've read, the 'ALL' type leads to poor performance.

I've added an index but it still says 'ALL' -- is there something else I must do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well you definitely figured out the necessity for indexing, but the key is knowing whether or not the indexes are actually fully optimizing your query.

MySQL uses indexes on columns at its maximum efficiency if the columns are the same type and size (i.e. CHAR(10), VARCHAR, etc.). You can alter your tables, ALTER TABLE, to ensure these types are consistent across the columns are you joining on.

Another thing that MySQL does is assume that values in the columns are evenly distributed, which might not be the case. If you run an ANALYZE TABLE on the table in question, you might find that the number of rows it returns are not even close to the actual number in the real table. To fix this you could use a different type of JOIN or even go so far as to reorder your tables in your FROM clause.

If the ALL type still hasn't gone away after these tests, it might be the case that the query is as optimized as it is going to get.